# Convert apache .htaccess rewrite rule to lighttpd

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I'm trying to convert apache .htaccess rewrite rule to lighttpd:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

By accessing the url /projekt?test=test , the print_r($_GET) in apache gives:

Array ( [q] => projekt [test] => test )

But if I follow the rules I found for converting this to lighttpd wich is the following rule:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
"^/([^.?]*)\?(.*)$" => "index.php?q=$1&$2"
)
```

the array becomes: Array ( [q] => projekt [?test] => test )

How can I change the lighttpd rule to remove the ? from the variable?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the request handling? `debug.log-request-handling = "enable"`

Comment: Your regex looks good to me, i just recommend the request handling because it'll let you see what lighttpd is doing during the rewrite. You'll need an error log specified.